# I'm trying to change an element in a 2D array but it won't change

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to change an element in my 2D array using user input but it wont change. How can i fix this problem? I looked online to find solutions but the solutions i found doesn't fix my problem. 
edit: I got it to partially work but now it changes other elements in the 2D array if you input for example 2A.

```
void grid()
        {
            int gridLength = 8;
            int gridWidth = 8;
            int index = 0;
            char gridLetter;
            int gridNumber;
            int numGrid[7][7];

            for (int pi = 0; pi <= 7; pi++)
            {
                for (int oi = 0; oi <= 7; oi++)
                {
                    numGrid[pi][oi] = 0;
                }
            }
            int ooo = 3;
            do
            {
                system("cls");
                int m = 0;
                char letter[8] = { 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H' };
                cout << "    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8  " << endl;
                cout << endl;
                for (int l = 0; l < 1; l++)
                {
                            for (int Jindex = 0; Jindex < 8; Jindex++)
                            {
                                cout << letter[m] << "   ";
                                m++;
                                for (int index = 0; index < 8; index++)
                                {
                                    cout << numGrid[Jindex][index] << "    ";
                                }
                                cout << endl;
                                cout << endl;
                            }
                }
                cout << "Chose which tile you want to attack(press enter after each selection (ie. A *enter* 4) " << endl;
                cin >> gridLetter >> gridNumber;
                int gridLetters;
                switch (gridLetter)
                {
                case 'A':
                    gridLetters = 0;
                    gridNumber -= 1;
                    numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber] = 1;
                case 'B':
                    gridLetters = 1;
                    gridNumber -= 1;
                    numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber] = 1;
                case 'C':
                    gridLetters = 2;
                    gridNumber -= 1;
                    numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber] = 1;
                case 'D':
                    gridLetters = 3;
                    gridNumber -= 1;
                    numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber] = 1;
                case 'E':
                    gridLetters = 4;
                    gridNumber -= 1;
                    numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber] = 1;
                case 'F':
                    gridLetters = 5;
                    gridNumber -= 1;
                    numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber] = 1;
                case 'G':
                    gridLetters = 6;
                    gridNumber -= 1;
                    numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber] = 1;
                case 'H':
                    gridLetters = 7;
                    gridNumber -= 1;
                    numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber] = 1;
                }


            } while (ooo = 2);
        }
```

Comment: remove `==` use `=` in this lines `numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber] == 1;`

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** `==` Use `=` in these lines `numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber] == 1;`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code & I tested id using this array,

```
int numGrid[2][4]{
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 5, 6, 7, 8 }
};
```

.... in this switch of yours you have a couple of statements testing for 1 & some are assigned the value 1 .... I guess it's a type error you meant to assign them all.
Your for-loop returns garbage numbers.
assume you meant...

```
for (int m = 0; m < _countof(letter); m++)
        {
            cout << letter[m] << "   ";
            for (int i{}; i < _countof(numGrid); i++)
            {

                for (int j{}; j < _countof(*numGrid); j++)
                {
                    cout << numGrid[i][j];
                }

            }
                cout << endl;
        }
```

but I could be wrong...

I'm presented with a screen which displays from 'A' to 'H' in individual
rows followed by numbers 1-8.
I select some values like A4...it seems to increment gridNumber through your loop by 4...

```
switch (gridLetter)
    {
    case 'A':
        gridLetters = 0;
        //gridNumber -= 1;
        numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber - 1] = 1;

    case 'B':
        gridLetters = 1;
        //gridNumber -= 1;
        numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber - 5] = 1;

    case 'C':
        gridLetters = 2;
        //gridNumber -= 1;
        numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber - 9] = 1;

    case 'D':
        gridLetters = 3;
        //gridNumber -= 1;
        numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber - 13] = 1;

    case 'E':
        gridLetters = 4;
        //gridNumber -= 1;
        numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber - 17] = 1;

    case 'F':
        gridLetters = 5;
        //gridNumber -= 1;
        numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber - 21] = 1;

    case 'G':
        gridLetters = 6;
        //gridNumber -= 1;
        numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber - 25] = 1;

    case 'H':
        gridLetters = 7;
        //gridNumber -= 1;
        numGrid[gridLetters][gridNumber - 29] = 1;

    }
```

I don't know how you want it to come out....but it looks wrong to me, I'd use a function,
can you post the entire program?

Comment: I'm trying to change the element they chose in the 2D array from 0 to a 1.

Comment: hey C.Kay....when you say "they" ...you mean a third person?, as for the input...like if I type "B0"..it will change the zero to 1 or do you mean it in a more Boolean sense?

Comment: yes it will change the element B0 to 1 if you typed it.

Comment: I got it to partially work now but it changes other elements in the 2D array for some reason.

Comment: yeah because its all contained in that loop of yours, you need to separate the displayed output into a function....that's your for-loop, it at the moment it outputs all as static, if you make a function the output will be unique because it's separate from the block.

Comment: if I type zero it wont do anything to the output already begins with one...if (gridNumber == 0)
   gridNumber = 1;

Comment: What if I type 'P' instead of "0"